# Pass the output of previous command to next command as a command

Tags: linux

One of Linux script on my machine shows long line of ssh command as a result, and then I copied the result and paste on terminal again and press Enter.  I would like to use the result as a next command.

For example,

```
Linux] abc_script
```

result is

```
ssh -L xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.com :1234;xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I would like to use above results, `ssh -L bla bla` to next command and Enter.

Comment: Then pipe the output to bash as in : `abcscript | bash`

Comment: Alternative ly, `abcscript | xargs -r -d'\n' -n 1`

Comment: So, the command outputs a shell command? What sort of stuff does that command contain exactly? Anything with quotes or pipes or multiple commands etc?

Answer (score 2):

One why to do what you want is to put the command in `$(...)`

```
# I can run ls
$ ls 
my_file

# I can have a command that generates "ls" as its output
$ echo "ls"
ls

# I can run ls by running a command that generates "ls" as its output
$ $(echo "ls)
my_file
```

In your case, it'd be something like:

```
$(abc_script)
```

Be very careful with this, however; the shell will run whatever the command prints.

Comment: I made alias  abc_script='f() { abc_script -r "$@" ssh-tunnel-command; unset -f f; }; f'

Comment: I made alias  abc_script='f() { abc_script -r "$@" ssh-tunnel-command; unset -f f; }; f'
When I type abc_script xyz and enter,
Results comes out as 
ssh -L 1234 bastion.123.xyz.xxxx.xxxxxxx :2345 xxxxx.xyz.xxxxx.xxxx
And then I normally copy above ssh -L 1234 bla bla and paste it on same window and press enter to access the server.
To minimize my effort (copy & paste & Enter),
I would like to make my alias, abcscript to login bastion without copy & paste.

Comment: @UncleJ did you try `$(abc_script xyz)` ?